# Docker container restart without data loss

Tags: docker, cassandra, rancher

I am using `Rancher` as orchestration tool. I have a single node `Cassandra` installed in a container and would like to restart it, because of I have made some changes in configuration file(`cassandra.yaml`) recently. There is already data in database, so would like to prevent data loss. I use `usman/docker-rancher-cassandra:3.1` image. Which command should use to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Restarting a container won't affect your data in the container. If you are trying to recreate the container with the new image, you may lose the data.***

If you are using volumes, your data will be persisted in the host. It depends on how did you started your container. You can check the volume info from `docker inspect <container_name>`.

By going through the [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/usman/docker-rancher-cassandra/~/dockerfile/) which you are using, the cassandra data directory is a volume.

```
VOLUME /var/lib/cassandra
```

If you explicitly mounted your container volume using

```
docker run -d -v <HOST_PATH>:/var/lib/cassandra usman/docker-rancher-cassandra:3.1
```

Then you can upgrade the container with new version. Otherwise, you need to copy the data from directory before recreating container.

**SOLUTION 1:**

Start another container from the volumes of an existing container.

```
docker stop cassandra
docker run -it --volumes-from cassandra \ 
               --name="cassandra-new" \
               usman/docker-rancher-cassandra:3.1
```

If everything works fine, remove the previous container and rename the container

```
docker rm cassandra
docker rename cassandra-new cassandra
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

docker inspect to get the volume path.

```
docker inspect <container_name>
```

[image]

You can copy the data from `/var/lib/docker/volumes/531419fb27d1dff9c5371769edc08d6160f71061c9fe3af05309a3a0c51bb84d/_data` to some other directory before recreating container. You need mount that directory while starting the new container using

`docker run -v <HOST_PATH>:/var/lib/cassandra`

Comment: Is there any method to export data from container and after restart import it? I haven't mounted it explicitly.

Comment: @KovacsAkos, Updated answer to recover your data from the container.